# How many processes are in memory at a given time

Tags: memory-management

Is there only one process in memory at a time and context switches constantly move processes back and forth between DRAM to disk? Or are multiple processes kept in DRAM at the same time, and context switches just change which process the cpu is executing?

how is this different for virtual memory?

Comment: How processes get loaded into memory has nothing to do with how processes get scheduled.

Comment: This question depends on the os, what you are describing is part of what the os does. I would say that given sufficient memory and modern os's processes will all be in memory until they terminate

Answer (score 1):

The question really doesn't make any sense.

Information gets loaded into, and kept, in memory based on how frequently it's used and the decisions made by the virtual memory manager. Processes are scheduled by the scheduler. One has nothing to do with the other.

It's not processes that are kept in memory in modern operating systems, it's pages. And if you imagine, for example, two processes running the same executable, many pages will be shared and loaded into memory, if needed, when either process accesses them.

Comment: By 'process' I mean pages of memory that makes up the process' address space. Can more than one of these 'processes address spaces'  be resident in physical memory at the same time? or only one?

Comment: Pages can be resident from any combination of processes.  Pages can even be resident that aren't mapped by any process. One basically has nothing to do with the other. Processes use pages, which force them to become resident in memory. They stay resident until either the OS wants to use that physical page for something else or they cannot ever be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

*Portions* of multiple processes' address spaces most certainly can be, and almost always are, in physical memory at the same time. It is very rare for all of a process's v.a.s. to be resident. It's almost as rare for none of it to be resident. (In fact, on Windows, since every process carries with it a small amount of nonpageable info, it's impossible. Dunno about other OSs but I expect it's the same.)

Memory is not paged in and paged out because of scheduling behavior—except that, of course, a thread that is not running incurs no page faults; if all of the threads in a process are not running, then there is no reason to page in any of its virtual address space.

Conversely, a long-idle process may have some of its memory reclaimed from its working set (and possibly, though not necessarily, lost from RAM) by the OS if there is a shortage of RAM and/or a high page fault rate.

You didn't specify which OS you were asking about. On Windows, Task Manager, "Processes" tab (Windows Vista and 7) or "Details" tab (Windows 8.x), "Memory (Private working set) will show you how much RAM is in the working set of each process, for process-private v.a.s. The "Memory (shared working set)" column tells you how much RAM is in the w.s. of each process that may also be in the working set of other processes.

In addition, there will usually be some pages that are associated with each of many processes on the modified and standby page lists. The standby list is part of what Windows reports as "Available", the modified list is not. These are not in any processes' working sets, but if the corresponding virtual pages are faulted to they can be "paged in" very quickly, without going to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I've occasionally thought about this from a philosophical perspective by trying to apply it to humans in order to think about our experience of some process. I used computers as a analog for us; consciousness is the product of the process of information which comes from memory.

That wasn't helpful for me, but I think it applies to your question because in a simple case, the answer would be yes.

In the CPU core, **if the process is the execution of** the procedure, we know the processor is working the data from its register memory. Maybe that's still not low enough. Going deeper, to the threshold of execution where the process results in *the* product, we'll see it end at the [arithmetic logic unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit). The ALU has the function of performing **an operation on two numbers**. So, that's why I say yes, if our view is limited here, there's only one process in memory at a time.

So:

- Registers = working memory (our buffer holding the information we soon experience as *now*, a few milliseconds after the fact)
- ALU = end threshold of process (last thing we do with that memory)
- Product/Output = consciousness (the result of the process)

This isn't an answer to the question, but I hope to get you thinking about the different levels and types of memory, and remembering that there's a physical machine at the bottom of it all. The answer assumes the ALU will finally complete the process from two inputs and a sole output. Modern CPUs are probably too complex for me to even say how many potentially final, sub ALUs are actually at the end of the unit.